# Start application with command line argument using Dogtail on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I started writing automation scripts for browser using Dogtail in Ubuntu, an open source GUI testing tool and automation framework written in Python. I am invoking the browser using:

```
run("firefox", appName="Firefox"); // Where appName is Window Name
```

But I want to start the browser with additional command line arguments (eg: --some-args). Is there a way to do something like this?

Reference: https://zmc.fedorapeople.org/dogtail/epydoc/dogtail.utils-pysrc.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that you can pass the arguments with the first 1st parameter of run i.e. "firefox --some-args". As run uses subprocess.Popen to launch the application and can take any number of command line args.